# Set output path for MSBuild task

Tags: msbuild

In the following simple MSBuild file I'd like to overwrite the output path that is defined in the .sln or .csproj file. In line 13 you can see that I call an MSBuild task for an existing VS solution. Usually, the projects that are part of that solution have a property where the output is stored. With my script I'd like to overwrite that so that my "build automation" uses a different directory than the default one.

```
<Project 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
    DefaultTargets="Default">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <appname>Some App</appname>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
        <file_xap>Some.App.WP8_$(version).$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(`yyyyMMddHHmmss`)).xap</file_xap>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Default">

        <MSBuild Projects="C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SomeApp\SomeApp.sln" Properties="Configuration=Debug;Platform=Any CPU">
        </MSBuild>
        <Message Text="Output file: $(file_xap)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

So the actual question is: How can I call MSBuild for that sln in a way that the output (the xap-file in that case) to another directory (having all the output apart from the xap-file is fine as well)?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895502/how-to-tell-msbuild-where-to-put-my-compiled-files ?

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: @MBH Sorry. Not yet.

Comment: I found it i will post the answer soon

Answer (score 1):

I will post my full xml here so you can understand it all
the structure of the project is like this:

```
MyProject----MyProject.sln
         ----MyProject.Server---    
                        ----MyProject.Server.proj
                        ----Other server project classes and stuff
         ----MyProject.Client---
                        ----MyProject.Client.proj
                        ----Client project related stuff
         ----BuildFromXmlFldr---
                                ----build_both_proj.xml <---This is the example file i posted here
```

Here is the build_both_proj.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
        ToolsVersion="4.0"
        DefaultTargets="Build">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <SolutionDir>..\</SolutionDir>

        <ServerProjectFile>..\MyProject.Server\MyProject.Server.csproj</ServerProjectFile>
        <ClientProjectFile>..\MyProject.Client\MyProject.Client.csproj</ClientProjectFile>

        <ServerProjectName>MyProject.Server</ServerProjectName>
        <ClientProjectName>MyProject.Client</ClientProjectName>

        <ServerOutput>C:\_Publish\Server\</ServerOutput>
        <ClientOutput>C:\_Publish\Client\</ClientOutput>

        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    </PropertyGroup>


    <Target Name="BuildServer">
        <MSBuild Projects="$(ServerProjectFile)" 
        Targets="Build"
        Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);OutputPath=$(ServerOutput);">
        </MSBuild>

    </Target>

    <Target Name="BuildClient">
        <MSBuild Projects="$(ClientProjectFile)" 
        Targets="Build"
        Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);OutputPath=$(ClientOutput);"
        StopOnFirstFailure="true">
        </MSBuild>
    </Target>




    <PropertyGroup>
        <BuildAllDependsOn>BuildServer;BuildClient</BuildAllDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="BuildAll" DependsOnTargets="$(BuildAllDependsOn)"/>
</Project>
```

This is the msbuild.exe command inside the folder `BuildFromXmlFldr` that I used:

```
c:\path_to_msbuild\MSBuild.exe build_both_proj.xml /t:BuildAll
```

so the output is determined in the `Properties` attribute in the `Target` tag

```
Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);OutputPath=$(ServerOutput);"
```